# Android - How to display the last part of TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

When a single line of text is too long, how can I make TextView always display the last part of it?

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_sum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="0.00"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I want this:

[image: I want this]

not this:

[image: I do not want this]

Comment: what do you mean by final content?

Comment: if final content means the last word or sentence of the text use "android:ellipsize = "start""

Comment: @LearningAlways he means to show the last part of the string

Comment: @Vall0n I think in this case it would `android:ellipsize="end" `

Comment: @InnerFire Either one of them. But i think start means show ellipse (...) at the beginning of the textfield

Comment: Sorry... My English is poor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think so the below code may help to you.

```
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.YourIdName)
horizontalScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_FORWARD);
            //Observe for a layout change
            ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = horizontalScrollView .getViewTreeObserver();
            if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        horizontalScrollView .fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I lengthen the text in the TextView, it works ok. But when I shorten the text, it will return to the front and gradually recede.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to set

```
 android:ellipsize="start"
 android:singleLine="true"
```

your textview should like

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="very big text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```